# Terraform: Deploy multiple Lambda aws_s3_bucket_notifications resources using a for loop

Tags: for-loop, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to deploy multiple aws_s3_bucket_notifications resources to an s3 bucket. I have the following main.tf file, which I am not confident is correct:

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_permission" {
  source_arn = "arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket}"

  for_each = {for i, item in var.schematic: i=>item}
    function_name = each.value.lambda_function_name
    statement_id = each.value.statement_id
    action = each.value.action
    principal  = each.value.principal
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
  #  depends_on = [aws_lambda_permission.allow_permission]
  bucket = var.bucket

  for_each = {for i, item in var.schematic: i=>item}
    lambda_function {
      lambda_function_arn = each.value.lambda_function_arn
      events              = each.value.events
      filter_prefix       = each.value.filter_prefix
      filter_suffix       = each.value.filter_suffix
    }
}
```

I want to create a dynamic amount of paired lambda permissions and bucket notifications for pre-existing bucket and lambda. The amount of pairs created should be driven by the number of objects in the input 'schematic' variable.

The following input.tf file:

```
variable "bucket" {
  description = "The bucket used by the lambda trigger."
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}

variable "schematic" {
  type = list(object({
    lambda_function_name = string
    lambda_function_arn = string
    statement_id = string
    principal = string
    action = string
    events = list(string)
    filter_prefix = string
    filter_suffix = string
  }))
}
```

and the output.tf file:

```
output "bucket_notification_bucket" {
  value = aws_s3_bucket_notification.bucket_notification.bucket
}
```

When I try to run this I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Missing resource instance key

  on ../../modules/resource/lambda/multiTrigger/outputs.tf line 2, in output "bucket_notification_bucket":
   2:   value = aws_s3_bucket_notification.bucket_notification.bucket

Because aws_s3_bucket_notification.bucket_notification has "for_each" set,
its attributes must be accessed on specific instances.

For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
    aws_s3_bucket_notification.bucket_notification[each.key]
```

First of all is the looping inside my main.tf file correct? Secondly how should my output.tf file look to account for the looping that is taking place?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to have all the bucket names but since you created the resource with `for_each` you have to either specify a key or you can get all of them using the [`values` built-in function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/values):

```
output "bucket_notification_bucket" {
  value = values(aws_s3_bucket_notification.bucket_notification)[*].bucket
}
```

Note that this will return a list.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they are all using the same bucket. You could grab the bucket name from the first `bucket_notification` in the set, but you could also just do this:

```
output "bucket_notification_bucket" {
  value = var.bucket
}
```